# How can I pass the product id in array while I can update inventory of all product ids at same time

Tags: php, magento

```
$productId= array('25545','23453');
```

When I vardump the result I'm getting an error:

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Please help how to solve this problem

Comment: I think the query would help

Comment: You sould provide more information and logicyou are trying to understand your problem